# push_pull operator not working using bpy scripting

Tags: operator

I'm procedurally placing objects (XY dimension only) around a central object, with some randomness to their distance/angle relative to the central object. Occasionally, this results in overlap between these placed objects.

To detect and remedy this, I'm using a cheap and easy method, of simply finding the distance between these objects, and comparing it to a known value, based on the size of the object being placed. If the objects are too close, i want to move them both directly away from each other. From the blender documentation, the operator "push_pull" looks perfect for this, and works just as I want to when using the GUI. Unfortunately, I cannot get it working using BPY python scripting. This is a demo version of what I'm trying to do:

```
    import bpy
    from math import sqrt


    def dist(a, b):
        dx = a.location[0] - b.location[0]
        dy = a.location[1] - b.location[1]
        return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)

    min_dist = 4 # minimum centre-to-centre distance for follower placement (prevent overlap)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
        location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(4, 4, 1)
    )
    Cube1 = bpy.context.object
    Cube1.data.name = "C1"
    Cube1.name = "C1"

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(
        location=(1, 1, 0), scale=(4, 4, 1)
    )
    Cube2 = bpy.context.object
    Cube2.data.name = "C2"
    Cube2.name = "C2"


    cubes_distance = dist(Cube1, Cube2)
    if cubes_distance < min_dist:
        print("TOO CLOSE")
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None
        Cube1.select_set(True)
        Cube2.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.transform.push_pull(value=(min_dist-cubes_distance))
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = None
```

Is this a problem of object selection / context? When I run this script in GUI, it doesnt return any errors, and the two cubes are selected in the viewport, but no push is applied

Answer (score 0):

Think I worked it out with some trial and error & reference to the (not particularly detailed) docs for push_pull.

I think you have to set the value argument to NEGATIVE if you want to push the objects away from each other, whereas positive values are "pull". IMO this is the wrong way round, but at least it works now!